# Stencil global style is not applying after publishing package and using in angular

Tags: angular, stenciljs

```
// stencil.config.ts
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';

export const config: Config = {
    namespace: 'mycomponent',
    outputTargets:[
        {
            type: 'dist'
        },
        {
            type: 'www',
            serviceWorker: null
        }
    ],
    globalStyle: 'src/global/variables.css'
}


// src/global/variables.css
:root {
    --qa-primary-color: #2169e7;
    --qa-secondary-color: #fcd92b;
    --qa-dark-color: #0000;
    --qa-light-color: #ffff;
    --qa-font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    --qa-font-size: 12px;
}
// index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/mycomponent.css">
```

This is working fine for me while running the stencil project but once I publish the package to npm and use in Angular these style is not getting applied. Please help

Comment: is the href to /build still valid?

Comment: its working in my stencil project

Answer (score 1):

The `/build/<namespace>.css` file is for the `www` output target. When you publish to NPM, it's the `dist` output target that gets published. Thus you need to reference the file as `/dist/<namespace>/<namespace>.css` instead, i. e. in this case

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/mycomponent/mycomponent.css">
```

Comment: I don't quite understand... if I just add that `<link>` to the index.html file - my project doesn't find the css file. (E.g., when I run `ng serve`, `http://localhost:4200/dist/mycomponent/mycomponent.css` is not found. Is there something else I need to configure? For what it's worth - I do see that css file in `/node_modules/mycomponent/dist/mycomponent/mycomponent.css`. It just seems like it's not making it's way up to my Angular project.